# How can turn my data (in an object) into the correct format ready to post request to an API

Tags: reactjs, json, forms, post

I have a form which is completed by the user. I have set it up so i have the response of the inputs and when console logging my data it returns in an object. I then need to post this data to an API that I have no control of. This data needs to be in a json and as nested objects.

How can then convert my response to this nested objects.

This is my current form data / response

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
    formData: {
      Email: "",
      Forename: "",
      Surname: "",
      Mobile: "",
      AmountToBorrow: "",
      Term: "",
      FinanceTypeId: "",
      Make: "",
    },
  });
```

This is the format i need it in to complete the POST request.

```
THIS IS THE STRUCTURE I NEED THE DATA IN!!!!
    {
      "Applicants": [
  {
  "Email": "APITESTING@test.co.uk",
  "Forename": "Olly",
  "Surname": "Test",
  "Mobile": "+447777777777"
  }
  ],
  "Vehicles": [
  {
  "Make": "Fiat"
  }
  ],
  "FinanceDetails": {
  "FinanceTypeId": "2"
  },
  "AmountToBorrow": 20000,
  "Term": 20
  }
```

I can complete this request fine on postman but now i am thinking my formdata is set up incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

When the form is submitted, you can simply create a new object based on your state and turn it into json before sending the POST request. Something like this:

```
const formattedData = {
  Applicants: [
    {
      Email: data.formData.Email,
      Forename: data.formData.Forename,
      Surname: data.formData.Surname,
      Mobile: data.formData.Mobile,
    },
  ],
  Vehicles: [
    {
      Make: data.formData.Make,
    },
  ],
  FinanceDetails: {
    FinanceTypeId: data.formData.FinanceTypeId,
  },
  AmountToBorrow: data.formData.AmountToBorrow,
  Term: data.formData.Term,
};

const jsonData = JSON.stringify(formattedData);
```

You can then pass `jsonData` as the body of your POST request.

Also consider removing the `formData` key from your state to simplify the code. For example, if your state looks like this:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
    Email: "",
    Forename: "",
    Surname: "",
    Mobile: "",
    AmountToBorrow: "",
    Term: "",
    FinanceTypeId: "",
    Make: "",
});
```

Then your formattedData looks like this:

```
const formattedData = {
  Applicants: [
    {
      Email: data.Email,
      Forename: data.Forename,
      Surname: data.Surname,
      Mobile: data.Mobile,
    },
  ],
  Vehicles: [
    {
      Make: data.Make,
    },
  ],
  FinanceDetails: {
    FinanceTypeId: data.FinanceTypeId,
  },
  AmountToBorrow: data.AmountToBorrow,
  Term: data.Term,
};
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for you help on the matter that worked. @Jbrown